# Enable Uglifier verbose logging in Sprockets-Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sprockets, uglifier

I have a Rails project where a newly added javascript file (`plotly.min.js`) is causing `rake assets:precompile` to hang indefinitely in production mode only. Since the problem is related to javascript compression, I would like to enable verbose logging for Uglifier. I can see that this is possible for the [UgligyJS2 command line tool](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage), but my question is how to enable this from my Rails app, preferable in an initializer or the like. I can solve the issue by changing my javascript compressor to `closure-compiler`, but I would like to identify the problem with uglifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the sprockets logger in the initializer:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new($stdout)

  # This sets the log level to debug
  Rails.application.assets.logger.level = 0
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't make any difference to the command output. Using `--trace` I get as far as `Execute assets:precompile` before it gets stuck.

Comment: I suppose you are talking about capistrano output? I just thought that `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` does not work for you locally

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with Capistrano. I'm just running the command locally on my machine and it's failing to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I don't have a proper answer to this problem either (I solved it for now by disabling the uglifier in production):

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
# KT TODO: reenable js compression
# config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

... but just to confirm that I ran into the same problem with uglifier and plotly.js.

Comment: I'd suggest trying the closure compiler instead, it was able to compile without errors for me.